# UI issues while executing UFT test via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft

I am having Jenkins running as a service and have a job to execute UFT tests on a remote slave. As part of the pipeline I am required to un-install our product, restart the slave, install the product (latest version) and start the test execution.
Since UFT tests need a dedicated UI, I am trying to launch a mstsc connection to the test VM from a temp VM. But since Jenkins is running as a service the mstsc process runs as a background process on the temp VM. Due to this UFT tests don't get a dedicated UI and some of the tests fail.

Tried running Jenkins using the war file instead of service. But after 30-40 mins or so the master slave connection drops.

Any workaround / tweak would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run your jenkins remote agent(war) as a normal Process and not as a service, otherwise, as you mentioned there is no Desktop for them.

My Proposal:

1. Make sure the jenkins remote agent is running as a normal OS process (on both VMs). You can have a Windows Scheduled Task that launches this Process on Logon and Checks every 5 minutes if it is still alive (if not restarts it)
2. After the Temporary VM (Let's call it a Gateway) woke up your  Test VM, the Test VM should execute a tscon command which will redirect the currently active RDP Session to the console (the Physical Monitor - which on Virtual machines well it's virtual). This will help you having your UI Session alive until the next restart, without having to bother about the Gateway
   [tscon here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tscon). Example: tscon **rdp-tcp#1 /dest:console**  This can be solved again with a Scheduled Task which is executed At Logon (waiting a few Seconds just to make sure)
3. Have Caffeine.exe or MouseJiggle.exe running in the background as Processes (also launched at Logon) on your Test Computers to make sure the SCreen is never Locked or any Screen Saver is activated. Both tools are free.
4. If your Jenkins Connection drops that is a different issue has nothing to do with UFT. In my case this combination works perfectly fine. It is also easy to automate the installation of these things. Windows Batch and Vbs can do all these things for you. (Putting the mentioned tools to your %PATH% and creating Scheduled Tasks Programmatically)

** Bonus Tipp: In order to avoid a taskkill java.exe command killing your remote agent, you can simply rename the java.exe of your jvm to jenkins_remote_agent.exe and use that as your jenkins remote agent executable

Answer (score 0):

UFT requires an interactive session for some Win32 operations.

In the Tools ⇨ Options menu, select General ⇨ Run Sessions there you will find an option to Enable continued testing on locked/disconnected remote computers, this may help in your case too.

[image: Screenshot of options]